# Where can I watch french films online?

Tags: cinéma

Bonjour tout le monde !

Je cherche un service comme Netflix, où l'on peut regarder des films français. Gratuits ou pas, cela ne fait aucune différence.

En particulier, je cherche le film "La science de rêve". Merci :)

Comment: @Toto I don't want to improve anything! Actually, I just want to watch some french movies online, that's it) Not utube channels!

Comment: @Toto filmfra.com is a good starting point but, unfortunately, it's not enough for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about the French language.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, ok, but maybe you could tell me where I should ask such a question? SO is my only hope)

Comment: https://www.google.fr :)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, sure thing! But is there something like french Netflix? Movie archives, you name it?

Comment: maybe on movies.stackexchange.com ;)

Comment: @Atarax thanks! I didn't know such site exists:)

Answer (score 0):

Le meilleur site que je connais c'est :

http://filmfra.com/

On peut regarder des films français sous-titrés ainsi que des films américains en leur version française (V/F) mais également sous-titrés

Il y a vraiment une pléthore des films à regarder.

**EDIT**

See also

[French movies/videos with French subtitles](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33988/french-movies-videos-with-french-subtitles)